# How can I make my Chrome to change the background color of webpages with a single click?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I know I could open the developer tools and change the CSS of a page every time I didn't like the dark background and the white letters. But I'm looking for a feature or extension that could switch that with a single button click every time I found a page like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this [Hacker vision](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hacker-vision/fommidcneendjonelhhhkmoekeicedej) Chrome Exstension for that. Try it out maybe it will suite your needs ;)
This exstension apply a high-contrast to all websites, and check for related ones.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome extension to change text&background color of webpage:

With mouse dragging, webpage color will change in real-time. You can drag to adjust until you feel satisfied.

Its installation link from chrome web store.

[Babu Color](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/babu-color/dkabogmdcebincpnhjkblipnceehimch)

It is very easy to use.